# Restart node when dust template changes

Tags: node.js, dust.js, nodemon, kraken.js

I'm using nodemon to restart node when files change.  It works fine when modifying .js files, but doesn't restart when modifying `public/templates/index.dust` file.

The  `.nodemonignore` file had a `/public/*` entry, which I removed, but still can't get nodemon to restart on `.dust` file changes.  Ideas?

Comment: in `nodemon.json` i saw an option name `ext` that looks like `"ext": "js json"`. Maybe you can add dust there? https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/doc/sample-nodemon.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodemon only looks for certain extensions by default.  From https://github.com/remy/nodemon#specifying-extension-watch-list

> By default, nodemon looks for files with the .js, .coffee, .litcoffee,
>   and .json extensions. If you use the --exec option and monitor app.py
>   nodemon will monitor files with the extension of .py. However, you can
>   specify your own list with the -e (or --ext) switch like so:

So what I have to do is launch nodemon with switch like this: `-e js,dust` or modify the `nodemon.json` file's `ext` property to include `dust`